# Lint error "Do not treat position as fixed; only use immediately and call myHolder.getAdapterPosition() to look it up later"

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm contributing to open source library and got lint error "Do not treat position as fixed; only use immediately and call myHolder.getAdapterPosition() to look it up later" for this code:

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyHolder myHolder, int i) {

```
    myHolder.recipeTitle.setText(mData.get(i).getRecipeName());
    myHolder.img_recipe_thumbnail.setImageResource(mData.get(i).getThumbnail());
    myHolder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,RecipeActivity.class);

            intent.putExtra("RecipeName",mData.get(i).getRecipeName());
            intent.putExtra("RecipeIngredients",mData.get(i).getRecipeIngredients());
            intent.putExtra("RecipeMethodTitle",mData.get(i).getRecipeMethodTitle());
            intent.putExtra("Recipe",mData.get(i).getRecipe());
            intent.putExtra("Thumbnail",mData.get(i).getThumbnail());

            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please take a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and ask a concrete question.